# no way to create / register first application

Tags: facebook, error-handling

I tried to create my first app.

I went to https://developers.facebook.com/ and clicked on 'applications'.

Then facebook redirected me to my facebook page. There was NO button to '+add an application' and no form to ask me if I needed 'something' to create the application.

I added a valid credit card because it's mandatory to get a 'developer' status.

How I can add an application to facebook. Is there a way to ask their tech department?

(edited)->
Also if I click on https://developers.facebook.com/apps it redirects me to my facebook page WITHOUT a window to 'Request for permision'
<-(edited)

Comment: Did you read the tutorial? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/

Comment: Dear Mat: thanks for your suggestion. YES, I TRYED to follow the steps of this tutorial, but in the first step 'Creating your app', and tried to ckick into 'Devveloper app' (developers.facebook.com/apps) it redirect me to my personal page. NO WINDOW asking me to 'Request for permission', nor window to ask me for someting, or telling that it needs something. So I CAN'T continue this tutorial.  Any help will be welcome. All the videos and tuts tell me that this window MUST be here but, in my case. NO window to continue. :-(

Comment: Are you using your personal account to add the developers application? Are you maybe using one of your pages accounts?

Comment: Dear Lix; Thanks. Where I cand find (into my personal account) to add a developers application? No see nothing when I click in 'Configuration' (top of my personal page). I'm logged in facebook. May be for this, when I click, it redirect me to my personal page. But no botton, prompt window for starting add app or log as developer. Do you suggest me to unlog  first and then goto developers.facebook.com/app ? (sorry my English)

Comment: You cannot use Page accounts to create applications.  They must be created from a personal user account.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) you will have a button to add New App, a popup should appear to write the New App's name. I can see in your post you don't get this popup, but it is where you need to go. So try using this link on your Personal Account not your pages account, just like DMCS is saying.

[Here](http://www.facebook.com/platform) you should get a couple of more links, and there's a *how to* link that might help.

<---edit--->

[Here](http://gathadams.com/2007/06/18/how-to-write-a-facebook-application-in-10-minutes/) you can find a fast track to build a facebook app. Not sure if it's what you want, but it might help in some parts of the process.

Comment: Dear Fernando and DMCS: Thanks for your explanation. Yes, it seems that no way to create app from 'page account' but from a 'personal account', but I don't find this 'issue' in the SDK or developers pages... and I think that it should be noted in a good place to avoid loss your time replying things like that to newbies as me. Well, so I think that I will be able to create an app from a (new) personal account to add content to the busisnes account without further limitations, right? I don't want we banned by facebook because I do something not allowed...

Comment: @Antuser1176684 Added a link to my answer, hope it helps a bit more.